# Calling Enum.values() on a generic type

Tags: java, enums, generic-programming

The goal is to implement a generic Enum translator. 
I know **Enum1** and **Enum2** have the same values and in the same order.

The goal is to implement something like this:(this works)

```
private static Enum1 translateEnum(Enum2 originalEnum) {
    return Enum1.values()[originalEnum.ordinal()];
}
```

But I have several enums, so I want to make a generic method: (this doesn't work)

```
private static < T extends Enum<T>,G extends Enum<G>> T translateEnum(G originalEnum) {
    return T.values()[originalEnum.ordinal()];        
}
```

My problem is that at **T.values()** the compiler tells me :

> The method values() is undefined for the type T

Do you guys have an idea of how I could solve this issue or do you have any alternative idea to my problem?

Comment: Pass `Class<T> clazz`? That said, though, this doesn't seem eminently useful; most systems include this sort of thing already.

Comment: @chrylis what do you mean by "most systems include this sort of thing already"?

Comment: If `Enum1` and `Enum2` truly have the same values and in the same order, why are there two of them?

Comment: Just in case `Enum1` and `Enum2` begin deviating, and not *"the same values and in the same order"*, it would be better to map by name, so deviating order is auto-adjusted, and missing value will throw exception. This is called [**defensive programming**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Defensive_programming).

Comment: @Andreas Enum1 is an external dependency of the project. Enum2 is a local version of it. About your second comment, I guess defensive programming is a good idea.

Comment: Then my previous comment about defensive programming becomes even more relevant, because you have no *guarantee* that external dependency is changed without you noticing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A common way to do this is to pass the target [class object](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) (or an object of the target class) as an argument to the function, then use methods from the class object to do the tricky part. For enum classes, the class object has [a method which returns the equivalent of Enum.values()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getEnumConstants--). You can use that to get the enum values from the target class:

```
public class Scratch {
    enum lower { a, b, c };
    enum upper { A, B, C };

    static <T extends Enum<T>> T translate(Enum<?> aFrom, Class<T> aTo) {
        return aTo.getEnumConstants()[aFrom.ordinal()];
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (lower ll : lower.values()) {
            upper uu = translate(ll, upper.class);
            System.out.printf("Upper of '%s' is '%s'\n", ll, uu);
        }
        for (upper uu : upper.values()) {
            lower ll = translate(uu, lower.class);
            System.out.printf("Lower of '%s' is '%s'\n", uu, ll);
        }
    }
}
```

Running this produces the following output:

```
Upper of 'a' is 'A'
Upper of 'b' is 'B'
Upper of 'c' is 'C'
Lower of 'A' is 'a'
Lower of 'B' is 'b'
Lower of 'C' is 'c'
```